# How to filter oData call using dynamic date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, odata

I'm making an AJAX call using URL as follows.

```
http://somecomputer/Service.svc/Method?$filter=SomeDate gt DateTime'2014-08-24'
```

This works perfectly and and the moment, I generate the string describing the date right before my AJAX call. However, I wonder if it's possible to match the date on dynamic values, such as *today* or *lastyear* or what not.

I haven't found any documentation of that when googling so probably it's not possible but I still need to check with the wisdom of SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is such thing as [Built-in Query Functions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793694) in OData that you can use in query options to represent dynamic values. From the link you can see that there is this function `now()` under the "Date Functions" category and the ODataLib has already supported it in the URL parser of its latest version. (see the release notes [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/6.6.0)).

But there are two things for you to note:

1. ODataLib only deals with the parsing of such functions in request URLs, the actual logic of it needs to be further implemented by the service implementers.
2. According to the look up of the OData V3 protocol (section 10.2.3.1.2 on [this page](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol)), V3 doesn't have such dynamic built-in query functions.

Comment: +1 for clarity. I interpret it as a "no, buddy, sorry" unless I take full(er) control over the implementations, which I'm not able to due to time concerns. I guess the best choice of mine is to go with JS rendering and simply editing the date when pasting in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. One example:

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10);
var url = "http://somecomputer/Service.svc/Method?"
  + "$filter=SomeDate gt DateTime'" + today + "'";
```

Comment: I realize that I wasn't clear in my question. Sorry about that. The approach you presented is what I'm using today. I'd like to know if it's possible to compare with a dynamical "today" directly, without preparing the string in advance. The reason is that sometimes I'd like to literally paste in the string in my browser to check what jumps out. Plus adding the dynamical date the way it's now (your way) is always a headache because I never remember the syntax and need to do trial-and-error. Still, +1 for clarity.    :)