# How use OData $filter query dynamic date

Tags: outlook, odata, powerapps, power-automate

I'm trying to use Microsoft Flow to fetch all my calendar events for the past two weeks, and do this every two weeks. The problem is that the "get all events" outlook action only accepts an ODATA $filter query and it's not clear how to filter it dinamically, something like:

```
$filter=Start ge Today()-14
```

Is that even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter oData call using dynamic date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471104/how-to-filter-odata-call-using-dynamic-date)

Answer (score 0):

Try to build **IF** statement with the following condition

```
StartDate ge @{adddays(utcnow(‘yyyy-MM-dd’), -14, ‘yyyy-MM-dd’)}
```

Please find more info at [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language).